# How to compress files in parallel in python

Tags: python, gzip

I have a directory with 500 files in a directory. Each of this file has to be compressed to .gz. Is there a way to run zipping in parellel instead of sequentially

Comment: Could you include whatever code you have already tried and explain why it was not sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) to run each compression task as a separate process.

Comment: In Python specifically, [since this is a CPU-bound task, no](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Threading).

Comment: That's interesting! How would you know it's already utilizing 100% CPU time though, since OP has not put that in his post?

Comment: He's doing file compression, which is very compute intensive. Unless he's reading/writing to a magnetic tape or floppy drive, he'll have enough disk IO speed to keep a single core pretty much fully occupied compressing a single file.